# Import WPA-EAP Wifi config from Mac OS X on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, wpa2

We have a serviced office and the company that provides the Wifi service only gives out a unique username and password and an .EXE file for Windows users to configure the Wifi connection, which is of type WPA-EAP. They don't support Linux. Strangely, MacBooks are able to connect to the Wifi with no additional configuration.

This made me think that it's using LEAP, but I tried to configure the connection for LEAP in Linux with the same username and password, but it kept failing to connect and asking for my password again and again. It's possible that this live USB doesn't have the right software installed for LEAP, or it's also possible I suppose that the Wifi won't let 2 laptops connect with the same username and password.

I couldn't figure out how to get the Macbook to dump its Wifi connection information so that I could configure the Linux laptop to connect as the same user. How might I do that?

Comment: You can inspect the Mac's configuration via System Preferences > Network > [Wi-Fi interface], and via the Keychain Access utility (where Wi-Fi credentials are stored).

Comment: System Preferences says it is "Authenticated via EAP-PEAP (MSCHAPv2)", and I exported the certificate as a PEM and tried to use that as the "CA Certificate", but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some certificate for the network provider in Keychain Access, but it was a red herring - i.e. no certificate was needed to connect to the wifi from Linux! The problem was simply that I needed to:

1. Go into System Preferences -> Network -> [Wifi interface] on the Mac and look for the authentication method, and use that
2. **Use my Wifi username as the "Anonymous identity"**